# Find the limit using Riemann sum

Tags: integration

Find the limit: 
$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left(\dfrac{1 + n}{n^2} \right)\left(\dfrac{4 + 2n}{n^2} \right)...\left(\dfrac{n^2 + n^2}{n^2} \right)}
$

I tried simplifying this limit and the one I get to is:

$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2}\bigg(\big(2n\big)!\bigg)^{\dfrac{1}{n}}
$

I have an instruction to write the limit as a definite integral and then calculate its value. I think that there should be a way to represent the last limit as a Riemann sum and then calculate it with the integral. But I'm not sure how to get to the Riemann sum.

Looking forward for any ideas!

Comment: +1 and welcome to our community! However, don't you think you can make the title of this question a bit better?

Comment: Considered your advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logarithm of the initial expression is
$$
 \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left(\frac{k^2+kn}{n^2}\right) = \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left(\left(\frac kn \right)^2 + \frac kn \right)
$$
which is a Riemann sum for
$$
 \int_0^1 \ln(x^2 + x) \, dx = \int_0^2 \ln x \, dx  = 2 \ln 2 - 2 \, .
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\;a_n=\dfrac{(2n)!}{n^{2n}}>0\quad$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

Since

$\exists\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left[\dfrac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)^{2n+2}}\cdot\dfrac{n^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right]=$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left[\dfrac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(n+1)^2}\cdot\dfrac{n^{2n}}{(n+1)^{2n}}\right]=$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left[\dfrac{4n^2+6n+2}{n^2+2n+1}\cdot\dfrac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{2n}}\right]=\dfrac4{e^2}$

by using an [application of Stolz-Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Geometric_mean), we get that

$\exists\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2}\bigg(\big(2n\big)!\bigg)^{\dfrac{1}{n}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{(2n)!}{n^{2n}}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\dfrac4{e^2}\;.$

Comment: Nice answer. I don't understand the use of the existential quantifier $\exists$ here.

Comment: It means that the limit exists, indeed there are limits that do not exist, for example: $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin n\;.$

Comment: I know, but to me, it is putting the cart before the horse, since when writing it, you don't know yet that the limit exists.

Comment: I know it because I have already calculated it, moreover if a limit does not exist, then it does not make sense to write that it is equal to something else. For example, it does not make sense to write: $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\;.$